# How to single test case for multiple values in karma

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have 2 arrays of data:

```
array_1=['temp1','temp2','temp3'];
array_2=['insert','delete','update']
```

I have test case to pass two values like

```
it('Should return type insert', function () {
    expect(scope.getActionType(array_1[some incrementer variable])).toBe(array_2[some incrementer variable]);
});
```

---

but i need to achieve this with out using a loop and using only one it could you some one help me with this.

```
'use strict';
 describe('app module', function() {

beforeEach(module('sampleApp'));

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('BaseController', {});
}));

describe('TestController', function() {
  var scope, controller;
      beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
          scope = $rootScope.$new();
          controller = $controller;
          controller('BaseController', {$scope: scope});
          controller('TestController', {
              $scope: scope
          });
          scope.action="insert" ;
  }));
  it('Should return type insert', function () {
      expect(scope.getActionType()).toBe('insert');
  });
  it('Should return type update', function () {
      expect(scope.getActionType()).toBe('update');
  });
  it('Should return type delete', function () {
      expect(scope.getActionType()).toBe('delete');
  });
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you say you do not want to use a loop, that you do not want to run a loop inside the test, thereby having a single test running multiple executions.

What you can do instead is put the loop outside the test like this:

```
for (var [value, expected] of [
    ['temp1', 'insert'],
    ['temp2', 'delete'],
    ['temp3', 'update']
]) {
    test_getActionType(value, expected);
}

function test_getActionType(value, expected) {
    it('Should return expected type (' + value + ' -> ' + expected + ')', function() {
        var result = scope.getActionType(value);

        expect(result).ToBe(expected);
    });
}
```

The separate function is necessary so that the anonymous function in the actual test closes over the correct values of the `value` and `expected` variables.